# Form validation summary in AngularJS with custom message per field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to render a validation summary on a page using AngularJS.  Here's what I have so far:

```html
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <form name="userForm">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User Info</legend>
                <p><label>Name: <input type="text" required ng-maxlength="15" name="name" ng-model="name" /></label></p>
                <p><label>Age: <input type="number" required name="age" ng-model="age" /></label></p>
                <p><label>Favorite Color: <input type="text" required name="favColor" ng-model="favColor" /></label></p>
                <p><input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="submitForm()" /></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div id="validationSummary" ng-show="hasValidationErrors()">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="error in validationErrors">{{ error }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my controller, I'm creating an array with all of the errors.

```js
function ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.hasValidationErrors = function () {
        return $scope.validationErrors && $scope.validationErrors.length > 0;
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        $scope.validationErrors = [];

        for (var property in $scope.userForm) {
            if ($scope.userForm.hasOwnProperty(property) && $scope.userForm[property].$invalid) {
                $scope.validationErrors.push($scope.userForm[property].$name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing I can't figure out is:  how can I get more than just the name of each field that is invalid?  I've noticed that there is also an `$error` property on each field.  Outputting this instead of `$name` gives me the following:

```js
{"required":true,"maxlength":false}
{"required":true,"number":false}
{"required":true}
```

So I can get the field name, and I can get an object that describes what is wrong with that particular field.  How can I define an error message, so that if a field is required it will output "{name} is required"?  It seems like this could be a data- attribute on the input element itself, although I don't know how I would access that attribute.

Of course, it's also possible that I'm making things entirely too difficult on myself.  Is there a better way to approach this while staying in the "AngularJS" world?

Here's a link to the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3JTyg/2/) I've been working on.

Comment: There is no built-in angular service that does this job. It will be yours to template or programatically build the sentences in a dedicated service which might inject $interpolate service.

Comment: @lib3d - thanks for confirming the nonexistence of a built-in angular service.  I couldn't find one, but it's reassuring to hear i didn't just overlook something obvious. I feel like I'm close with what I have so far, if only I could have `data-required-message="blah blah"` and then do something like `$scope.userForm[property].getAttribute('data-required-message')`.  How might that part work?  How can I access the element from within that for loop in my controller?  And should I use data attributes or some sort of custom directive or something else?

Answer (score 3):

A far easier and cleaner way is [demonstrated here](http://plnkr.co/edit/05oDTf?p=preview)

Simply put (where form1 is your form name attribute):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, errors) in form1.$error track by $index"> <strong>{{ key }}</strong> errors
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="e in errors">{{ e.$name }} has an error: <strong>{{ key }}</strong>.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

**A totally dynamic validation summary based on [AngularJS 1.5.7 with ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) using field names that the user recognizes**

A template with error messages:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="error-messages">
  <span ng-message="required">This field is required.</span>
  <span ng-message="email">Please enter a valid email.</span>
</script>
```

Display of the error summary (here for a form named "candidateForm"):

```
      <div data-ng-if="candidateForm.$submitted && candidateForm.$invalid">            
          Please correct these fields and then try to send again:
          <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="field in candidateForm" data-ng-if="candidateForm[field.$name].$invalid">
              <div>
                {{ getValFieldName(field) }}
                <span data-ng-messages="candidateForm[field.$name].$error" role="alert">
                  <span data-ng-messages-include="error-messages"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

A helper function to get the name of the label associated with the input field (instead of displaying input field names or "internal ID codes" to users):

```
$scope.getValFieldName = function (field) {
  return $("label[for=" + field.$name + "]").text(); // to get label associated with input field
  // return $("#" + field.$name).attr("placeholder"); // to get placeholder of input field
};
```

You can reuse this set of standard error messages on multiple forms, ngMessages ensure only one error displayed per field, and looks like the fields are listed in the order they appear in the HTML.

Should probably be made into a directive instead of the jQuery-style helper function, and might even want to add a click-handler on each error message to scroll to the input field with the error. Maybe another will run with that idea?

Comment: This was very helpful.  I was trying for about an hour and a half to find a way to customize the Angular error message "name" field attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Use below line to get values of every text box

```
var value = $scope.userForm[property].$name;
var vl =$('*[name="' + value + '"]').data('required-message')
$scope.validationErrors.push(vl);
```